# приветствие в тг группе aiogram3

Tags: python, aiogram

почему когда пользователь входит в консоль ничего не пишет (роутер присоединен к диспетчеру), JOIN_TRANSITION = IS_NOT_MEMBER » MEMBER

```
@router.my_chat_member(
    ChatMemberUpdatedFilter(
        member_status_changed=JOIN_TRANSITION
    )
)
async def new_member(event: ChatMemberUpdated):
    try:
        print("123")
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

В функции start_polling теперь нужно явно указывать allowed_updates.
Не знаю, как у вас это реализовано, но попробуйте так:

```
async def main():
    dp = Dispatcher()
    bot = Bot("токен")
    await dp.start_polling(
    bot, 
    allowed_updates=["message", "inline_query", "chat_member"]
)
```

Осторожно с табуляцией, но главная суть: передайте такой allowed_updates!